# Double integral with dependent variable

Tags: integration, self-learning

I have computed the red area.

[image]

Which I can compute with this double integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1}^{x+1} dy dx = 1/2$$

or with a single integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1} (x+1) dx - \int_{0}^{1} dx = 1/2$$

However, what does this integral computes, graphically?

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1}^{x+1} (x+1) dy dx = 5/6$$

There is no online calculator that shows me a graph of this double integral, so I'm really struggling with this intuitively. I have come up with this problem when dealing with probabilities: I usually have an f(x,y) where I need to compute certain ranges for integrals, but I can't figure out the relationship between the domain when it's variable-dependent, and the f(x,y).

Comment: The first integral is the area that you depicted. The second integral is the volume of the function $f(x,y)=x+1$ under that area. Imagine that in three dimensions.